# preg_replace: Ignore already replaced parts

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace a date pattern string (intl extension) with the corresponding input fields.

The patterns can be:

```
dd.MM.yy
dd.MM.yyyy
M/d/yy
M/d/yyyy
dd/MM/y
dd/MM/yyyy
```

My code is:

```
$date_pattern = 'M/d/yy';

$search = array('/[d|dd]/', '/[M|MM]/', '/[y|yy|yyyy]/');
$replace = array(
'<input type="text" name="day" size="2" maxlength="2">',
'<input type="text" name="month" size="2" maxlength="2">',
'<input type="text" name="year" size="4" maxlength="4">');

print preg_replace($search, $replace, $date_pattern);
```

The problem is, that "preg_replace" matches already the first replaced input field at the position:

```
<input t[here because of the 'y' character]pe="text" ...>
```

Is there any way to tell preg_replace to ignore already replaced parts?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361943/php-preg-replace-function-replacing-previous-matches. To be honest, it's easier to either make just one regex and replace all the parts at once, but I think the answer to your specific question is that you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't seem right as `[d|dd]` only matches `d` or literal `|`.

Better use word boundaries in your regex as this:

```
$search = array('/\bd{1,2}\b/', '/\bM{1,2}\b/', '/\b(?:y{1,2}|y{4})\b/i');
print preg_replace($search, $replace, $date_pattern);
```

**Output:**

`<input type="text" name="month" size="2" maxlength="2">/<input type="text" name="day" size="2" maxlength="2">/<input type="text" name="year" size="4" maxlength="4">`

Comment: `y{1,4}` does also match `yyy`.

Comment: By the way: your patterns result in: `<input type="text" name="month" size="2" maxlength="2">/<input type="text" name="da<input type="text" name="year" size="4" maxlength="4">" size="2" maxlength="2">/<input type="text" name="year" size="4" maxlength="4">`. Check the word boundaries again.

Comment: Thanks @Gumbo, yes there was a an issue in edit by ioseb. It is corrected now.